# What effect would 2 Luna-like moons have on an Earth sized (and ecologically Earth-like) planet?

Tags: science-based, planets, physics, gravity, moons

Assume for the sake of argument that both moons are very similar to ours, in size and composition. Perhaps one is slightly smaller than our moon, while the other is slightly larger.

Furthermore, in what ways do the orbits and hemispheric positions of the moons influence tidal stresses on the planet?

PS: I am a writer and illustrator researching for an alient world in my graphic novel. I'm new here and really enjoy reading everyone's contributions and discussions. Any answers or suggestions regarding my question would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/27883/34386
Also https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/112/34386