# How would two moons work on a planet?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, earth-like, moons, life

I'm planning on making a "new world", in a new planet. This planet would have similar living conditions to the Earth, but two moons (both in the same orbit, so that both can be seen at night), but I want to know how that works. How would it affect the planet? (I mean, in terms of wildlife and atmosphere).

The other question listed as a duplicate doesn't answer my question. I'm wondering about wildlife, and the other is about tides.

Thanks!

Comment: Your first question might already have been asked on this site. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-would-having-multiple-moons-affect-tides Many planets have multiple moons. All it would take is having one with liquid water to ALSO make it viable for life... the two moons can orbit at different distances and would never (or rarely) meet.

Comment: In addition to @IsaacKotlicky's comment, [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/30946/19951) may also be relevant

Comment: Does it count if the habitable planet is one of the moons?

Comment: Note that all of your individual questions already have answers on WB.  But, we want one question in a post.  So you can find *different* posts describing the effects of 2 moons, the possibility of two moons in different configurations without colliding, different options for distances, etc.  (Even without being duplicated, this post os *too broad*, being multiple separate questions.)

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79372/effect-of-two-moons-on-wildlife   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/78610/how-could-a-tiny-second-moon-minimally-affect-earth  etc.  See the [tag:moons] tag, and from these posts mentioned look at the *linked* and *related* lists.

Comment: And welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: Do the other posts and WB content answer yiur question, or is there still something you want to know?

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question. I'm wondering about wildlife, and the other question is about tides.

Comment: @C.Marshall how does the current moon impact our atmosphere and wildlife? It doens't.

Comment: @Mormacil That's what you think. But for instance, if a planet had two moons, then night would be brighter, and night-hunters (I mean animals, of course) would have to adapt to that. So would the preys. Also, if there are two moons, that would mean lower and higher tides. Would that mean a change to ocean creatures? Would they change and evolve to make themselves different? That sort of thing I'm talking about.

Comment: Two moons don't make the night brighter, only if their surface area is larger then our moon, if both are significantly smaller the nights would actually be darker. In itself they have no direct impact, they can impact the the world which would impact evolution but it's not the moons directly. As for alternate evolution, that's far to broad to ask here.