# Short and Long Term affects of another Moon

Tags: moons

What would the Short Term effects be on the earth is another heavenly body, similar in size of our current moon were to suddenly appear in orbit?  I would assume large tidal activity, perhaps even tectonic and severe meteorological effects.

What would the earth look like 50 to 100 years later, after this cataclysmic event?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to describe the additional moon's orbit before this question is answerable. *Do not* put it "in the same orbit as the current moon on the other side of Earth," because that position is not stable and the two moons will collide within a few years. The result of *that* is "rocks fall, everyone dies."

Comment: Particularly if this moon is of similar mass to and in any orbit nearby our current moon, you've got a particularly egregious case of the [three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem), so without precise orbital information, the answer can range from "both moons leave Earth" to "rocks fall, everyone dies".

Comment: Agree with John Dallman, you need to decide first, how wide the orbit is. Else you can't know the effects. Earth's moon orbit diameter is 768,000 km, don't go near that with another big one! our moon is already quite big.

Comment: Is it too late to just change the gravitational constant of the universe?

Comment: @cactusknight tip, use a WB search,. there's a lot of similar rogue moon topics and questions, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=moon+collide

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-would-having-multiple-moons-affect-tides), [here](https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/universe/earth-one-moon.html), [here](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-Earth-had-multiple-moons-instead-of-one) and [here](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-if-earth-had-two-moons-tides-sea-level-collision-2019-1).

**Tides**

There could be more than two high tides per day.
If the two moons are in same direction, tides will be very high causing tsunamis.

**Earthquakes**

Volcanic activity will increase with more earthquakes.